# Can this statement be written in one line?

Tags: coffeescript

Just for curiosity, can this function be written in one line, or at least the `for` part producing the same output?

```
getById = (id)->
    for e in array
        return e if e.id is id
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RvpvE/) for playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getById = (id) -> return e for e in array when e.id is id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
getById = (id) ->
  return e for e in array when e.id is id
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about 'when'... you where first but I'm accepting Jimmy's answer for being 'one line' :P